# Xamarin Forms Theme source

Tags: xamarin.forms, themes

Is there any way to adjust xamarin forms default themes or even view their original source code? Could not find any repository for Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Light.
Some theme template would be very helpful.

Thanks!